# Rhythombox doesn't run m3u files

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

i'm trying to listen to some radio station by downloading a m3u files and open it then sync with the server and then running the radio 
the problem that rhythombox doesn't running that files
any help ??

Comment: What happens when you open `m3u` files with rhythombox? any error?

Comment: no just it's not playing at ever

Comment: Rhythmbox 2.98 has 2 bad bugs in 13.04 (which I can't believe no Ubuntu developers seem to listen to music), crashes when syncing with ipods, and streaming radio is broken. In fact, every time you try to stream a radio station it will create a new zombie process on your computer. Best thing to do is downgrade to 2.97 until there are fixes for these.

Comment: @eshowcase how to downgrade to 2.97 ??